# What's the largest circle that can fit in a given regular 2-D shape?

Tags: geometry

Consider a triangle with all of it's side-lengths equal to 1. From the centre of this triangle, consider a circle. How big can this circle be without going over the edges of this triangle? What about other shapes? Is there a generalised formula? What about in 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

You can do this! First figure out the angle at the corners of any  such regular figure, and then consider the triangle between the mid point of the figure/circle and two adjacent corners... and consider the fact that the radius of the largest fitting circle is the length of the line from the midpoint to the midpoint of two adjacent corners.

In other words, the tangent of half of the angle is the radius of the circle divided by $\frac{1}{2}$. Since you the value of (half of) the angle, you can use the arctan function to figure out the radius.